# Writing case statements

Tags: bash, if-statement, switch-statement, case-statement

```
#!/bin/bash
until [read command -eq "end"]
do
echo What command would like to run?
read command
if [$command -eq "my-tweets"]; then
node liri.js $command
fi
if [$command -eq "do-what-it-says"];then
node liri.js $command
fi
if [$command -eq "spotify-this-song"]; then
echo What item would like to query?
read item
node liri.js $command $item
fi
if [$command -eq "movie-this"]; then
echo What item would like to query?
read item
node liri.js $command $item
fi
done
```

I am trying to create a case/if statement to check the value of a variable before running the next part of the code.  I want to check the value of `$command` to create this case/if statement according to the value of the user input. I keep getting the command not found error.

Comment: Indent your code.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the syntax errors @PSkocik pointed out, when you have a number of mutually exclusive `if` conditions, it's generally clearer/better to use `if ... elif...` instead of a bunch if separate `if` blocks:

```
if [ "$command" = "my-tweets" ]; then
    node liri.js "$command"

elif [ "$command" = "do-what-it-says" ];then
    node liri.js "$command"

elif [ "$command" = "spotify-this-song" ]; then
...etc
```

But when you're comparing a single string (`"$command"`) against a bunch possible strings/patterns, `case` is an even clearer way to do it:

```
case "$command" in
    "my-tweets")
        node liri.js "$command" ;;

    "do-what-it-says")
        node liri.js "$command" ;;

    "spotify-this-song")
...etc
esac
```

Additionally, when several different cases all execute the same code, you can include multiple matches in a single case. Also, it's a good idea to include a default pattern to deal with strings that don't match anything else:

```
case "$command" in
    "my-tweets" | "do-what-it-says")
        node liri.js "$command" ;;

    "spotify-this-song" | "movie-this")
        echo What item would like to query?
        read item
        node liri.js "$command" "$item" ;;

    *)
        echo "Unknown command: $command" ;;
esac
```

And as for the loop: generally, you'd either use something like `while read command; do` (note the lack of `[ ]`, because we're using the `read` command, not the `test` aka `[` command); or just use `while true; do read ...` and then check for the end condition and `break` out from inside the loop. Here, it's probably best to do the latter:

```
while true; do
    echo "What command would like to run?"
    read command
    case "$command" in
        "my-tweets" | "do-what-it-says")
            node liri.js "$command" ;;

        "spotify-this-song" | "movie-this")
            echo What item would like to query?
            read item
            node liri.js "$command" "$item" ;;

        "end")
            break ;;

        *)
            echo "Unknown command: $command" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was a great crash course into exactly what I was looking for.  The code is working perfectly right now.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets need spaces around them. `[` `]` isn't a shell language feature, `[` is a command name that requires a closing `]` argument to make things look pretty (`[read` will search for a command (executable or builtin) literally named `[read`).

String comparison inside `[` `]` is done with `=`, `-eq` is for integer comparison.

You should peruse the [dash(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) manpage or the [POSIX shell language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). They're not that big (Bash is bigger). You'll find the syntax for the `case` statement in there too.

Comment: Also, double-quote all variable references. `if [ $command = "my-tweets" ]` will give an error if `$command` is blank or contains multiple words or... several other conditions. `if [ "$command" = "my-tweets" ]` will work.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This really helped.  I was able to quickly get my code to evaluate whether a command was equal to a set value and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage of case in bash based on a argument.

```
case "$1" in
    argument1)
        function1()
        ;;

    argument2)
        function2()
        ;;  
    *)
        defaultFunction()
        ;;  

esac
```